# Disabling ajaxSetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 js files:

**app.js**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error : function(request) {
        switch (request.status) {
            ...
            case 422:
                App.handle422(request);
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

**race-registration.js**

```
var RaceRegistrationProxy = {

    url : App.getContextPath() + "/api/event",

    submitRegistration : function(raceId, eventId, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : this.url + "/" + eventId + "/" + raceId + "/registration",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType : "application/json",
            beforeSend : function(request) {
                App.setHeader(request)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
...
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("[id$='-message']").hide();
    var data = {
        'team_name' : $("#teamName").val(),
        'category_id' : $("#categoryId").val(),
        'members_ids' : memberIds
    };
    RaceRegistrationProxy.submitRegistration(raceId, eventId, data)
                         .done(registrationOk)
                         .fail(registrationFail);
});
...
```

How to disable the ajaxSetup when an error occurs in this specific method? I already tried use **global : false** in the submitRegistration method.

Comment: [**Note:** The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings. For that reason we *strongly recommend against using this API*. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

Answer (score 1):

I add the error atribute to the ajax call in the submitRegistration method.

```
submitRegistration : function(raceId, eventId, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : this.url + "/" + eventId + "/" + raceId + "/registration",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType : "application/json",
            beforeSend : function(request) {
                App.setHeader(request)
            },
            error : function(){}
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override it by passing the option each ajax call

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new
>   settings, **unless overridden by the individual calls**, until the next
>   invocation of $.ajaxSetup().

like:

```
return $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : this.url + "/" + eventId + "/" + raceId + "/registration",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : "application/json",
    beforeSend : function(request) {
        App.setHeader(request)
    },
    // here you overrite $.ajaxSetup().
    error : function() {}
});
```